# authentication fails after submiting - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt-ruby

I am trying to make simple authentication/registration ruby app. I am using BCrypt gem for crypting and it now gives me some problems. When I press submit button it throws

```
undefined method `password_salt=' for #<User:0x007f93c36bc570>
```

Ok, so I red that this code should be places from model to coontroler, but that gave me this er

```
undefined local variable or method `encrypt_password' for #<User:0x007f93c5f35f10>
```

I have tried rake db:migrate and restarting app also
git repo: https://github.com/pumpurs/auth

(code im talking about)

```
def encrypt_password
if password.present?
  self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
end
end
```

controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @user = User.new
end
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user].permit(:password, :email, :password_confirmation))
  if @user.save
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
else
  render "new"
end
  end

  private

  def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:password, :email, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

model file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :salt
  before_save :encrypt_password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create 
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
   def encrypt_password
if password.present?
  self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
end
  end
end
```

Comment: are you trying to save actual password to db or the encrpyted password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 attr_accessor :password_salt
```

in model?

Why don't use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or another authentication gem?